# neural network high misclassification rate

Tags: classification, neural-networks, overfitting

I have to create a binary classifier for a dataset of approx 150 samples and 50 binary features. The classifier has to be a feedforward neural network (NN).

My problem is that while the NN performs extremely well on the training set (approx 3-4% misclassification rate) it produces large test errors (approx 40-45%). I think this is a clear case of overfitting the data.

I tried two things so far to reduce the number of features:

1. I tried to reduce the number of hidden nodes, and even eliminate them, but to no avail.
2. I created an autoencoder (50-X-50 NN, with X hidden nodes, X=15,20,...40) to map the original dataset to a lower dimension. Unfortunately the reduced dataset behaves as bad as the original.

Any idea what should I try? (I don't have access to more data).

Comment: Your sample is to small for this issue, you need more data.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc: As far as I know a NN with no hidden nodes (in this case a 50 inputs, 1 output NN) and tanh activation is equivalent to a linear regressor. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes it is some sort of ADALINE. At the end many learning systems look like multiply and add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

50 features is a way too much for 150 samples. Autoencoder won't do anything good, unless you have access to large amount of unlabeled data. trying to apply autoencoder to just 150 samples unlikely to improve things much.

Try do the following:

1. If you don't use early stopping, use it. Its by far simplest method of regularization and usually good one. (stop training when error on your development set stop improving)
2. Design better features. Start from removing unuseful ones, and use separate development set to find ones that work best. Maybe start from minimal set (one or two features). Having better features can help more than anything else.

Other things that might help:

- use simpler model with smaller number of neurons up to a single neuron (logistic regression)
- try simple regularization like L1 and L2 regularization
- try "advanced" regularization methods like dropout, dropconnect, or full bayesian learning (this can be practical for your problem size and usually work good)
- consider generating synthetic dataset (sometimes it is possible to apply transformations to existing data that are known to preserve class label and make more data this way)
- try using different classifier, like decision trees or SVM

if everything fails, you need more data, perhaps you can get unlabeled data samples to use autoencoders or stacked RBM. Without knowing the nature of your classification problem, I can't recommend anything better.